# Spring login with mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, authentication, thymeleaf

I using **spring** with a **mongodb** and **thymeleaf**. My problem is that I don't know how I connect the login query with my user database. I already check the password (with hashing) but I only can query users which are initialized in the

```
@Override
public void init (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

method. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have it! This [guide](http://www.jroller.com/jbrosan/entry/spring_security_and_mongodb) and @helmy's post was a good help. The extra point is to write

```
@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(mongoSecurityService);
}
```

if you don't use .xml configuration and add an `CustomMongoService`. Thanks!

EDIT:

You should have the class `WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in your project folder. In this class write this:

```
@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public CustomMongoSecurityService mongoSecurityService;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(mongoSecurityService).and()
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("1234").roles("ADMIN");
    }

}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Where should I put this init ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest and most common approach is to implement your own `UserDetailsService` which will have a `loadUserByUsername()` method that will get a UserDetails object from MongoDB.

[Here](http://codesilo.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/mongodb-spring-data-and-spring-security-with-custom-userdetailsservice/) is a good tutorial, based on XML configuration. You may also want to check out the [Spring Security docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-authentication-manager) on how AuthenticationProviders work.

Comment: But unfortunately I still do not know where i should put the .xml's in my project. I don't have any .jsp file in it

Comment: Is there any tutorial for thymeleaf + spring + mongodb?